# RuntimeError: Working outside of request context (Flask)

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    encoded = message['image']
    decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    processed_image = preprocess_image(image, target_size=(224, 224))
    prediction = model.predict(processed_image)

    test_image_probs = {prediction[0][0] * 100 : "Cat" ,
                        prediction[0][1] * 100 : "Dog"}

    test_image_probs = {v: k for k, v in sorted(test_image_probs.items(), reverse=True)}

    testimage_prob_sorted_keys = list(test_image_probs.keys())
    testimage_prob_sorted_values = list(test_image_probs.values())

    prob_key_1 = testimage_prob_sorted_keys[0]
    prob_value_1 = round(testimage_prob_sorted_values[0], 2)

    prob_key_2 = testimage_prob_sorted_keys[1]
    prob_value_2 = round(testimage_prob_sorted_values[1], 2)

    response = {
        'prediction' : {    
            'prob_key_1' : prob_key_1,
            'prob_value_1' : prob_value_1,
            'prob_key_2' : prob_key_2,
            'prob_value_2' : prob_value_2
            }
        }

    return jsonify(response), prediction
```

how to pass return value (prediction) to use in another function?

i tried this :

```
prediction = predict()
prediction = prediction[1]

def abc():
    global prediction
    a = prediction[0][0]
    return a

a = abc()
print(a)
```

and an get error : 
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

Comment: Outsource `prediction = model.predict(processed_image)` to another function maybe?

Comment: sorry, can you please explain what do you mean by outsource to another function, thanks.

Comment: Just write another function, something like `def get_prediction(processed_image)` that returns `model.predict(processed_image)` and then you can call it from the view or anywhere else. In general your view function could benefit by being refactored into smaller functions.